# In Bash, how do I get user input for a date, and then search for files created for that date?

Tags: linux, bash, date, scripting, find

What I was trying to do is use find type -f with newermt options, but then I realized I need to advance by one day to get my results and thats where I'm stuck.  For instance:

```
find . -type f -newermt 20150505 -newermt 20150506
```

This works great, so I was going to have the user put in the date. So:

```
/myscript.sh 20150505
```

But the problem is, I would have to advance the users input date by one day, and that seems like a mess (for obvious reasons).  Also, having the user put two dates in to invoke this script is unwanted.  Can someone supply a better solution, or maybe there is a way to convert their input into an actual date, let linux advance it by a day so it makes sense?

Comment: so given an input X from a user you want to `find ... -newermt X -newermt (X+1day)`?

Comment: What does `-newermt` do, and why does it need to be specified twice? (Given that the primaries are implicitly ANDed, it seems like `-newermt 20150505` would always be true if the other one was, making it redundant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNU `date` to advance the date:

```
currentday=$1   # If this is 20150505, then ...
nextday=$(date +%Y%m%d --date "$currentday +1 day") # ... this is 20150506
```